# Luröth's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, rational-functions, principal-ideal-domains

I've been struggling trying to understand the Jacobson's Basic Algebra vol. II proof of the Luröth's theorem.

Let $K$ be a field, $K(X)$ the field of rational fonctions and take $L$ to be a sub-extension of $K(X):K$ such that $L \neq K$. Let $F \in L - K$. Then some lemma states that $X$ is algebraic over $K(F)$, it follows $X$ algebraic over $L$. Then let,
$$
\Phi = T^n + f_1T^{n-1} + f_{2}T^{n-2} + \cdots + f_0 \in L[T]
$$
be the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $L$. Now comes the strange assertion made in Jacobson's book :

There is a polynomial $P_n \in K[X]$ of least degre such that,
$$
P_n \Phi = P_nT^{n} + P_{n-1}T^{n-1} + \cdots + P_0 \in (K[X])[T] 
$$
and such that $P_n \Phi$ is primitive. I suppose we can take $P_n$ to be the least common multiple of the denominators of the $f_i \in L \subset K(X)$ but then I can't see why the greatest common divisor of the $\{ P_0, \ldots P_{n}\}$ is $1$.

So the question is why is it true ?

From the way Jacobson's states this assertion, it seems easy to see this but I tried very hard and failed.

Some insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. By letting $P$ to be that least common multiple of the denominators of the $f_i$s you get **a** polynomial $P(X)$ such that
$P\Phi\in K[X][T]$. It may initially happen that the coefficients 
$P_0(X),P_1(X),\ldots,P_n(X)$ have a non-constant common divisor $d(X)$. But the $P(X)=P_n(X)$ is also a multiple of $d(X)$, and we can use $\tilde{P}(X)=P(X)/d(X)$ instead of $P(X)$ to begin with. After all, the coefficient of
$\tilde{P}\Phi$ are the rational functions $P_i(X)/d(X)$ that we now know to be polynomials.

Mind you, I think that it follows from this that we actually must have had
$\gcd\{P_0,P_1,\ldots,P_n\}=1$ all the time.

Comment: Thanks ! I finally got it ! If there was a non trivial common divisor $D(X)$, we can reformulate the equation like $D(X) Q_n(X) \Phi(T) = D(X) Q_n(X)T^n + \cdots D(X)Q_0(X)$, where $deg_X Q_n < deg_X P_n$, simplify by D(X) and get that Q_n is also a multiple of the denominators of the f_i, but that would mean $P_n | Q_n$ because $P_n$ is a l.c.d., but that contradicts with the degrees ??

Comment: better : That $\tilde P_n$ you get is also a common multiple of the denominators so we get $P_n | \tilde P_n$ so $d(X)$ is invertible in $K[X]$, i.e. $gcd\{P_0, \ldots, P_n\} = 1$